# scanf to string and use if with it

Tags: string, if-statement, printf, scanf

I'm still new at programming C and I searched so much for a solution, but couldn't find one..
I'm trying to ask the user to enter the letter c or f and do the correct printf according to the letter of choice.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void startScreen();
char choice[1];

int main()
{
    startScreen;
    _getch();
    return 0;
}

void startScreen()
{

    printf("Please choose c or f\n");
    scanf("%s", choice);
    if (choice[0] == 'f' || choice[0] == 'F')
        printf("Good choice");
    if (choice[0] == 'c' || choice[0] == 'C')
        printf("Good luck");
}
```

Appreciate all the help I can get, thank you!

Comment: Why are you creating a global array of 1 character `choice[1]` instead of simply using a `char` variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Chad Estes and Ahmed Aboumalek, I combined what you both pointed at and it worked!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void startScreen();

int main()
{
    startScreen();
    _getch();
    return 0;
}

void startScreen()
{
    char c;

    do 
    {
        scanf_s("%c", &c);
        switch (c) 
        {
        case 'f':
        case 'F':
            printf("Good choice");
            break;
        case 'c':
        case 'C':
            printf("Good luck!");
            break;
        default:
            printf("Invalid input. Try again.");
            break;
        }
    } 
    while (c != 'c' && c != 'C' && c != 'f' && c != 'F');
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to mark this as the answer, glad we could help.

Comment: Will be able to do that tomorrow according to the rules :)

Answer (score -1):

My C is quite rusty, but I imagine the issue you're having is when you call this and input something other than 'C' or 'F'.  Looks like you need to alter your startScreen() function like so:

```
void startScreen()
{
    printf("Please choose c or f\n");
    do {
      scanf("%s", choice);
      switch(choice[0]) {
         case 'f':
         case 'F':
           printf("Good choice");
           break;
         case 'c':
         case 'C':
           printf("Good luck");
           break;
         default:
           printf("Invalid input. Try again.");
       }
    } while (choice[0] != 'c' && choice[0] != 'C' && choice[0] != 'f' && choice[0] != 'F');
}
```